# Which exchanges still accept USD wire transfers? (Oct 2012)

Tags: wire-transfers

Are there any exchanges left accepting USD wire transfers? I heard mention of sending to Dwolla and then transferring to Intersango, but only for U.S. citizens.

Answer (score 1):

Dwolla is only for this in the U.S. and the type of bank transfer they do is ACH, which is specific to banks in the U.S.

As far as exchanges that accept wire transfers directly, there are many, including:

- [Mt. Gox](http://mtgox.com) (Japan)
- [BitStamp](http://www.BitSTAMP.net) (EU)
- [BitFloor](http://BitFloor.com) (U.S.)
- [BTC-E](http://btc-e.com) (Russia)
- [Bitcoins Direct](http://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=87094.0) (U.S.) (bulk sales, minimum $500)

Many various methods here:

- http://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Buying_bitcoins